# How can access sublayout control from another sublayout in Sitecore?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have master layout and three sublayout header, content, footer. In header sublayout I have search textbox and search button, On click of search button result will display on content sublayout, On content sublayout I have repeater but I am not able to access repeater control in header sublayout.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dealt with similar problems in Sitecore sites before. There are two ways of doing this that I'd suggest you consider:

1) With some custom code, your Layout can act as an intermediary for the SubLayouts

Define some sort of "receive results" interface that can be implemented by any sublayout that wants to handle search results. For example:

```
interface IRenderSearchResults
{
   void RenderResults(IEnumerable<SearchResultData> resultSet);
}
```

Make your "content" sublayout implement this interface, so that when something sends it search results, it can handle them:

```
public class ContentSublayout : Sublayout, IRenderSearchResults
{
  public void RenderResults(IEnumerable<SearchResultData> resultSet)
  {
     repeaterControl.DataSource = resultSet;
     // do whatever other data binding tasks are required
  }
}
```

Then extend your Layout to have methods for "register me to receive search results" and "send search results to wherever they're needed":

```
public class MyLayout : Page
{
  private List<IRenderSearchResults> resultControls = new List<IRenderSearchResults>();

  public void RegisterSearchResultsControl(IRenderSearchResults control)
  {
    resultControls.Add(control);
  }

  public void DispatchSearchResults(IEnumerable<SearchResultData> resultSet)
  {
     foreach(var control in resultControls)
     {
        control.RenderResults(resultSet);
     }
  }
}
```

Your "content" control should then register itself when it's created, by calling the register method on the Layout. Add a method like:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyLayout layout = (MyLayout)this.Page;
  layout.RegisterSearchResultsControl(this);
}
```

Finally, when your header control has generated the results to display, it should dispatch them with a call to the Layout:

```
public class MyHeader : SubLayout
{
  public void DoTheSearch()
  {
    // whatever you do to perform a search

    MyLayout layout = (MyLayout)this.Page;    
    layout.DispatchSearchResults(theSearchResults);
  }
}
```

(This code was typed off the top of my head, rather than copy/pasted - so there may be typos - sorry)

That way any set of results receiving controls can exist anywhere on a page (and can be added / removed via Page Editor if you want) but whenever a search is run, if they're on the page they will get the results. This approach can also allow you to make things like the paging UI for the results, or a results summary display into separate controls that editors can move around the page.

Note that if you have multiple Layouts on your site, you probably need to make sure that the dispatching code is in a base class of all your Layouts, to make sure it's always available if an editor changes the layout of a particular page.

2) You could probably use Sitecore's event model
This article gives a fairly helpful description of how the internal framework for events works: https://adeneys.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/decoupling-through-the-sitecore-event-pool/ but there are others if you google.

Comment: Thanks Davis...I tried second option and it is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to use the querystring to hold the search parameters, which is the standard tried and tested way to do this.

When the user presses the search button you then need to redirect to the current page with the quersytring parameters added. Then have the sublayout with repeater read the querystring parameters to list the results, rather than pass data from one sublayout to another.

The use of the querystring means that users can bookmark search results and removes the need for a complex event model.

Also by using the browser layout as an intermediary for passing data means you are tightly coupling the sublayout and the browserlayout which may not be good if you need to use the sublayout else where.